# The scale of layers is changing in the print composer between different project in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale-bar

I am working on a project which have to layers of the word. In this project the world state are displayed as polygons with point and line layers.

All the layers are display on raster from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-raster-data).
I need two layers with different polygon colors that will much in scale and  location precisely.
I saved each layer as a different project and when I export them from print composer the upper layer.
[image] 
The layer is a little bit off from the bottom layer [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that this is a known bug in QGIS.
I could not fix, but I find a way around for this kind of projects.
For the sake of simplicity I will show me way around on a project with one raster layer and one vector layer.

I open the print composer with me raster layer in the required scale. [image]

Then I go back to the project and adding the next layer. The print composer is still open and I click on the Update preview bottom. The new layer is updating and the scale and position are remaining the  same.

[image].

I admit that it is not the most elegant solution, but it the only way I can find to solve this problem.